# When passing a class by-value, does the caller or callee call the destructor?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, destructor

Suppose that I have the following (trimmed down) code:

```cpp
class P { P(); P(const P&); ~P(); }

void foo(P x) {
  ...
}

void bar() {
  P p{};
  foo(p); // compiler uses P::(const P&) to construct the value for x
  ...
  // compiler calls P::~P() on p
}
```

The compiler must create a copy of `p` in order to call `foo`, so the *caller* invokes the copy constructor before the call. My question is, who is in charge of destroying this created object? There seem to be two valid choices:

1. The callee (i.e. `foo`) calls the destructor on all of its by-value arguments before it returns and then the caller deallocates the memory (by popping it off the stack).
2. The callee doesn't do anything, and the caller (i.e. `bar`) calls the destructor on all of the temporaries before the sequence point at the end of the `foo(p)` call.

Comment: As a general rule - the one who created destroys.

Comment: Is there a reason to need to know?  If it is just curiosity, take a look at the generated assembly for your platform.

Comment: I would like to know why you did ask this question. If you say "just for the knowledge" - it would be acceptable for me. I'm quite sure that destruction of temporary is done on caller side. However, what issue could be solved relying on this? (Not that I would rely on this.) ;-)

Comment: @Eljay That doesn't really answer the question. Seeing something happen a particular way on your platform doesn't guarantee that all conforming implementations will do the same thing.

Comment: +1 for @BrianBi. I just want to add an example for the consequences of the two possibilities. I reckon the example is questionable as far as good practices are concerned but it's still legal C++: assume that `~P`  throws (argh!!! I know) and nothing in the body of `foo` throws. If `bar` calls `~P`, then `foo` can be safely marked `noexcept`. If `foo` calls `~P`, then it cannot be safely marked `noexcept`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The standard answers this question in [expr.call]/4, with a surprising amount of elaboration:

> ... The initialization and destruction of each parameter occurs within the context of
>   the calling function. [ *Example:* The access of the constructor, conversion functions or destructor is checked
>   at the point of call in the calling function. If a constructor or destructor for a function parameter throws an
>   exception, the search for a handler starts in the scope of the calling function; in particular, if the function
>   called has a *function-try-block* (Clause 18) with a handler that could handle the exception, this handler is not
>   considered. *—end example* ]

In other words, the destructor is invoked by the calling function.

Comment: for completeness shouldn't you mention c-functions and c-structs (no\trivial destructors) ,which are also part of C++? Those typically have stack cleanup in the callee.

Comment: So, is the destructor called immediately after the function is executed, or since it is in the context of the calling function, is it destroyed when the calling function exits?

Comment: @Chipster also in that paragraph: "It is implementation-defined
whether the lifetime of a parameter ends when the function in which it is defined returns or at the end of the enclosing full-expression."

Answer (score 2):

The caller destroys it. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime. Quoting:

> All temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the
>   full-expression that (lexically) contains the point where they were
>   created, and if multiple temporary objects were created, they are
>   destroyed in the order opposite to the order of creation.

Also keep this as general rule - one, who creates, destroys. Usually in reversed order.

Answer (score 0):

The destructor is called whenever an object's lifetime ends, which includes

> end of scope, for objects with automatic storage duration and for
>   temporaries whose life was extended by binding to a reference

So `bar` which is the owner of copied object will call `dtor` on the copied object.
[Cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor)

Answer (score 0):

The idea of caller and callee looks wrong for me. You should think of `scopes` here.

In the moment the stack for the function is created where the object `P x` in `foo` comes to live, the object will be "created". As this, the object will be deleted at last by leaving the scope, in your case by leaving the function.

So there is no theoretical difference by having a local scope inside a function which introduces new objects and later on leaving this scope in the same function.

The compiler is able to "see" how your object is used, especially modified and can by inlining the function also skip the creation of a "temporary" object as long as the code behaves "as if" written.

Answer (score 0):

My short answer is, it depends on the ABI you are using.

Following Eljay's advise, I did a simple experiment with clang on Linux x86-64 and Windows 64 to understand why I failed generating code to call extern C++ functions on both ABIs.

Here is the code sample:

```
class A
{
public:
  ~A();
};

void foo(A a)
{}
```

Here is the llvm IR for the foo function on Linux x86-64:

```
; Function Attrs: noinline nounwind optnone uwtable mustprogress
define dso_local void @_Z3foo1A(%class.A* %0) #0 {
  ret void
}
```

Here is the same on Windows 64:

```
; Function Attrs: noinline nounwind optnone uwtable mustprogress
define dso_local void @"?foo@@YAXVA@@@Z"(i8 %0) #0 {
  %2 = alloca %class.A, align 1
  %3 = getelementptr inbounds %class.A, %class.A* %2, i32 0, i32 0
  store i8 %0, i8* %3, align 1
  call void @"??1A@@QEAA@XZ"(%class.A* nonnull dereferenceable(1) %2) #2
  ret void
}
```

The destructor is clearly called by the callee function on Windows 64 **but not** on Linux x86-64.