# Query about local copy of object and working of copy constructor

Tags: c++, pass-by-value

I have few confusions about what exactly happens when you pass the object by value, and about working of copy constructor.
To practice the concept, I wrote the following code.

```
#include <iostream>
 using namespace std; 
 class Cat
{
 public:
  Cat();
  Cat(Cat&);
  ~Cat() { cout << "Destructor called\n";}
  int itsage;
};
 
 Cat::Cat()
{
 cout << "Constructor called\n";
 itsage=2;
}
 
 Cat::Cat(Cat& )
{
 cout << "Copy constructor called\n";
 itsage=50;
}
 
 Cat myFunction(Cat Frisky)
{
 cout << "Frisky's age: " << Frisky.itsage << "\n";
 Frisky.itsage=100;
 cout << "Reassigned Frisky's age: "<< Frisky.itsage << "\n";
 return Frisky;
}
 
 int main()
{
 Cat Mani;
 cout << "Mani's age: " << Mani.itsage << "\n";
 myFunction(Mani);
 cout << Mani.itsage;
 cout << endl;
 return 0;
}
```

I got output as:

```
Constructor called
Mani's age: 2
Copy constructor called
Frisky's age: 50
Reassigned Frisky's age: 100
Copy constructor called
Destructor called
Destructor called
2
Destructor called
```

I have understood the first six lines of output. I have read that when you pass or return the object
by value, a temporary copy of object is made. So, temporary copy of `Frisky` got
creared when statement `return Frisky` got executed. But it got destroyed immediately as it was not assigned to
anything. This I think produced seventh line of output making first call to destructor. The output on line nine
and ten is also clear to me. I am confused about the eighth line of output which makes the second call to destructor.

**Doubt 1:** What exactly got destroyed in the second call to destructor? When we made call to myFunction via statement `myFunction(Mani)`, local copy of `Mani`
got created. After copy constructor finished, `Frisky` also got created in `myFunction`. Now when `myFunction` ended, what got destroyed? local copy of `Mani` or `Frisky`?

**Doubt 2:** Where this local copy of object is stored? Means when I called `myFunction`, where is local copy of `Mani` gets stored? Inside `myFunction`, inside `main` or somewhere else?

**Doubt 3:** Copy constructor is also one kind of function. Then in the header, in the parameter list, we only mentioned parameter type `Cat &` but didn't write parameter name. I have read that it is ok not to write parameter name in function prototype but when we are writing function definition, we should write type and name both. Is Copy constructor exception to this rule?

Comment: You discard the value that `myFunction` returns, so when the function returns both the temporary objects (the one for the argument and the one for the returned object) are destructed.

Comment: Try to output `this` on the console in every creation/destruction methods. It will help you understand the sequence.

Comment: @nop666 I am printing message like "constructor called", "destructor called".. Did you mean anything different? I didn't get what you suggested.

Comment: @nop666 If you print the object own address via `std::cout << this << std::endl;` in construction/destruction methods, you will see the relative order of construction/destruction for the local `main` object, the by-value parameter and the by-value returned object.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am confused at one point. I am thinking that there are four things that should get destroyed, 1. the local copy of ```Mani```(which got created by calling ```myFunction```) , 2.local copy of  ```Frisky``` (which got created when we returned Frisky), 3. ```Frisky``` itself (when myFunction ended), 4. And finally ```Mani```.  I am understanding something incorrectly. Please correct me.

Comment: There's something called [*copy elision*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision) which help with a [*return value optimization* (RVO)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision#Return_value_optimization) that  means the returned object will not be copied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is, the "copy" constructor `Cat::Cat(Cat &)` doesn't copy the value of `itsage` but sets it to an arbitrary value. Thus, passing a `Cat` object by value and returning it will yield strange results since the received objects don't resemble the original object.

**Details:** The parameter `Frisky` of the function `myFunction` is passed by value. This means calling `myFunction` will copy the passed object "into" `Frisky`. The copy will be constructed by the copy constructor `Cat::Cat(Cat &)`. Since this constructor sets `itsage` to `50`, `myFunction` always reports an age of `50` regardless of the original passed value.

The same applies here to the return values: Returning an object from a `myFunction` constructs a copy for the caller by using the copy constructor `Cat::Cat(Cat &)`. The returned copy always has a value `itsage=50`.

**Solution**: Write a proper copy constructor:

```
Cat::Cat(const Cat &other)
  : itsage(other.itsage)
{ }
```

Or even better: Use the default one by simply omitting the copy constructor. This default constructor essentially does the same as the above mentioned and comes for free.

If you really wish to modify the value passed to `myFunction` and to see these modification outside of `myFunction`, you need to pass the parameter `Frisky` by reference:

```
Cat myFunction(Cat &Frisky)
{
    // ...
}
```

**Answers to your doubts:**

1. The first destructor call is from the parameter `Frisky` which ends its lifetime when the function `myFunction` returns. The second destructor call is from the returned object. Since it never get used it is destructed right after the call of `myFunction`. The third destructor call is the end of the lifetime of `Mani` at the end of `main`.
2. Right before entering `myFunction` a local copy of `Mani` is stored on the stack and can be referenced inside `myFunction` by `Frisky`. It will be destroyed at the end of `myFunction`.
3. Yes, you can omit the name of a parameter but in the case of a copy constructor this is nonsense. A copy constructor should construct an object similar to the passed object. Since that it needs to access the state inside the passed object.

**Lifetime:** The following diagram shows the lifetime of the various objects of class `Cat`:

```
int main()
{                                                                       Mani        
    Cat Mani;                                                   Frisky   -+-
    myFunction(Mani)                                            -+-       |
                            Cat myFunction(Cat Frisky)           |        |
                            {                                    |        |
                                Frisky.itsage=100;    Return     |        |
                                return Frisky;        -+-        |        |
                            }                          |         |        |
     -(*)----------------------------------------------+-        |        |
    ;-(*)--------------------------------------------------------+-       |
    return 0;                                                             |
}-(*)---------------------------------------------------------------------+-
```

The `(*)` denotes roughly the moment, when their destructors are called.

You asked, why there is no destructor call for the local copy of `Mani`. The only local copy (I'm not entirely sure, what you mean by that) of `Mani` is created in order to get an object called `Frisky` inside the function `myFunction`. You don't need any further copies of `Mani`.

Comment: How the parameters and return value are handled in low-level code depends on multiple parameters (compiler, calling conventions, optimization level). [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/qqWY1z) is a typical example where the by-value parameter and the return object are stored on the caller stack frame.

Comment: @phlipsy Thanks for your answer. I have one doubt. Why there is no destructor call to local copy of ```Mani``` ? The first one is for Frisky, second for local copy of Frisky which is returned,  third for Mani, then why not for that local copy of Mani?

Comment: @phlipsy as suggested by @nop666 I added following line of code ```std::cout << this << std::endl;``` in constructor/destructor.. the first destructor call was for return object and second was for ```Frisky```. Just thought to let you know abt this.

Comment: @believer: You're absolutely right and I fixed it in the diagram above. As [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56584522/71051) explained: The caller destroys the value-parameters. Thank you for pointing this out!